# Thumbnail quality in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am going to create a slideshow app reading images from Google Drive. The images in Google Drive are mostly in high resolution. Therefore, I have to resize them to 1000x1000 and save to my server to display the slideshow.

I figured that there is a "thumbnailLink" (e.q. "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/{hash}=s220") attribute in service.files().get() API, and I can simply modify the link to return 1000x1000 by replacing "s220" to "s1000"  However, the image quality from thumbnailLink doesn't look so good. Finally, my solution was to download the entire hight-resolution images to my server and resize them.

It would be nice if Google Drive API can provide higher resolution thumbnails or have a attribute in thumbnailLink to set the image quality, that would save much bandwidth transfer between Google Drive and my server.